# In MSDOS, ask the person to input an existing file name and then delete it

Tags: assembly, masm, dos, dosbox, x86-16

I wrote the program below, but it's not working. I'm entering the filename as `dur.txt`. It's returning AX=4C03. Why is it not working and how can I correct it?

```
.model tiny
.data
  max1  db  32
  act1  db  ?
  inp1  db  30 dup(0)
  hande dw  ?

.code
.startup
    ;enter the name of the file
    lea dx,max1
    mov ah,0ah
    int 21h

    ;delete the file
    mov ah,41h
    lea dx, inp1
    int 21h
.exit
end
```

Comment: The characters you get in `inp1` includes the final cariiage return. Presumably the name of the file you're trying to return doesn't contain any carriage return.

Comment: use good old "debug.com", trace into the program up to behind the first int21h, and see what's inputed ... it's not really what int 21/41h expects ;-)

Comment: It's delete, not deleate (title, code comment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as Michael said correctly, the [ENTER] you press is also stored inside the input buffer. You have to replace it with a 0 before you can call int 21/41

```
    start: 
        ;enter the name of the file
        lea dx,max1
        mov ah,0ah
        int 21h

        mov si,offset act1  ;    inc si is coming before cmp, so start ahead
    lookup:
        inc si
        cmp byte ptr [si],0Dh
        jnz lookup
        mov byte ptr[si],0

        ;delete the file
        mov ah,41h
        lea dx, inp1
        int 21h
```

hint: if you "inc si" after the compare, you'll destroy it's flag settings. so I moved the inc si ahead of the compare, and SI had to be loaded one byte ahead of the buffer.
ps: the lookup is quite simple (and dangerous, it's not stopping before it find ANY 0x0D in memory!), i'm pretty sure there is a x86 loopup instruction somwhere :-)

as (again) Michael stated (again) correctly, the 2nd byte of the input buffer will tell, how long the entered string was (and where the 0x0d is, for it is the last letter entered). So there'S no need to search it, it's at [ inp1 + [act1] ]

```
start:
    lea dx,max1             ;enter the name of the file
    mov ah,0ah
    int 21h

pick:
    mov si,offset inp1      ; get offset of entered string
    xor bh,bh
    mov bl,[act1]           ; and it's len (the CR should be there)
    mov byte ptr [bx+si],0  ; replace it with a 0

    mov ah,41h              ;delete the file
    lea dx, inp1
    int 21h
```

Comment: `act1` will contain the number of characters read, excluding the carriage return. So there's no need to search for the CR character since you know ehere it's located.